# css fill remaining height, only when children require

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a content and a footer panel. Footer has fixed size, but content can be either fixed or fill remaining height, depending on (grand)child elements. If any child fills remaining height, then the content panel should also fill remaining height.
The depth of such filling childs can be any (immediate childs or 10 nested levels)

Example:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('child-switcher');
var child = document.getElementById('content-filler');
button.onclick = function() {
 if (child.style.display === 'none') {
   child.style.display = null;
  } else {
   child.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#footer {
  background-color: green;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#some-nested-content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content-filler {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#content-header,
#content-footer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<button id="child-switcher">
  Hide/show the child
</button>
<div id="content">
  <div id="some-nested-content">
    <div id="content-header">
      CONTENT_HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="content-filler">
      FILLING REMAINING HEIGHT
    </div>
    <div id="content-footer">
      CONTENT_FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

In the example, if you press a button, FOOTER stays at the bottom, but it  **should** go up.

PS using flexbox is not a requirement, it can be any layout, which will allow to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the example, if you press a button, FOOTER stays at the bottom, but
>   it should go up.

When you remove (set to `display: none;`) the flex item `content-filler`, the `content` will still fill the remaining space with its `flex: 1`, and keep the `footer` at the bottom.

> If any child fills remaining height, then the content panel should
>   also fill remaining height.

One way to solve that is to simply toggle a class on `content`, that toggle its `flex-grow` value.

> The depth of such filling childs can be any (immediate childs or 10
>   nested levels)

Here I also used the same class to control the `content-filler` element, as it is better to do that with a class than to change the element's style direct, and you can easily target any number or levels of elements.

Stack snippet

```js
var button = document.getElementById('child-switcher');
var parent = document.getElementById('content');
button.onclick = function() {
  parent.classList.toggle('collapse');
}
```

```css
#main {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#footer {
  background-color: green;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content.collapse {
  flex: 0 1 auto;                           /*  added  */
}
#content.collapse #content-filler {
  display: none;                            /*  added  */
}

#some-nested-content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content-filler {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#content-header,
#content-footer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <button id="child-switcher">
  Hide/show the child
  </button>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="some-nested-content">
      <div id="content-header">
        CONTENT_HEADER
      </div>
      <div id="content-filler">
        FILLING REMAINING HEIGHT
      </div>
      <div id="content-footer">
        CONTENT_FOOTER
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

---

Option 2 is to make a markup change, and move `footer` inside the `some-nested-content` element

Stack snippet

```js
var button = document.getElementById('child-switcher');
var child = document.getElementById('content-filler');
button.onclick = function() {
  if (child.style.display === 'none') {
    child.style.display = null;
  } else {
    child.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#footer {
  background-color: green;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#some-nested-content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content-filler {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#content-header,
#content-footer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <button id="child-switcher">
  Hide/show the child
  </button>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="some-nested-content">
      <div id="content-header">
        CONTENT_HEADER
      </div>
      <div id="content-filler">
        FILLING REMAINING HEIGHT
      </div>
      <div id="content-footer">
        CONTENT_FOOTER
      </div>

      <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @LGSon, thank you for the answers. 
Option 1 requires JS, which I wanted to avoid.
Option 2 is very good, but I cannot change html structure for the footer indeed.
If there will be no better options, I'll accept your answer

Comment: @buggy How is the `content-filler` hidden/showed in the first place, if not with JS?

Comment: You are right, JS is used for hiding/showing the filler. But I wanted to avoid using JS for managing layout and make CSS to do all the work automatically (if possible)

Comment: @buggy Then as you can see in my answer, when using a class as I did, you kind of get both, where script sets just set one class, and then with CSS selectors you make use of that class to control the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**Why is the footer sticking at the bottom?**

The problem lies with the **fixed height** you have set for the main container with flex display. If you just remove that height or set it to auto. Since, **#main isn't a flexible item** itself, it retains the entire height, but since its contents are flexible they collapse to the top.

**But then the content-filler doesn't occupy a full space?**

It doesn't occupy any space because now there is no height in question.You can just set a **min-height** to content-filler or just let it grow dynamically. Once, you hide it all the footers align to the top since the main container doesn't have a fixed height anymore.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('child-switcher');
var child = document.getElementById('content-filler');
button.onclick = function() {
 if (child.style.display === 'none') {
   child.style.display = null;
  } else {
   child.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#footer {
  background-color: green;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#some-nested-content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content-filler {
  flex: 1;
  min-height:200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content-header,
#content-footer {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<button id="child-switcher">
  Hide/show the child
</button>
<div id="content">
  <div id="some-nested-content">
    <div id="content-header">
      CONTENT_HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="content-filler">
      FILLING REMAINING HEIGHT
    </div>
    <div id="content-footer">
      CONTENT_FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Highdef, thank you for the answer. But I think it's not a solution:
1. There should be **no** min-height on the child. It can schrink to any size
2. #main container is out of the question/change, it can be 100vh, 100% or whatever. #content should be able to fill it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are talking about can be solved by use of [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

CSS Grid Layout excels at dividing a page into major regions or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer, between parts of a control built from HTML primitives.

If you want to have a good look that what can you do by using CSS Grid. I would recommend visiting this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

I hope this helps.